# axios get params does not inherit the params in create

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api, axios

Playing around with youtube api and reactjs

I am calling youtube api.  Recently noticed there is `create` in `axios` so I wanted to use it but somehow `params` kept on overwritten

What am I doing wrong here?

I have a file named `youtube.api`

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',
    params: {
        part: 'snippet',
        key: 'blahkey',
    }
});
```

then inside my react `handleOnSubmit`
    import youtube from '../apis/youtube';

```
handleOnSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.query);
    const response = await youtube.get('/search', {
        params: { q: this.state.query }
    });

    console.log(response, 'response');

};

console.log(response, 'response');
```

I get an error of `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=book 400`

the `params` of `part` and `key` are missing from the url though.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that this might be due to new version issue.  I am using `"axios": "^0.19.0"` which is causing this issue.

I downgrade it to `"axios": "^0.18.0"` and `"axios": "^0.18.1"`, both worked fine

P.S.
I went through their issue tickets on github and this was posted 6 days ago https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2190

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the version of Axios helped me.

To downgrade the version

kill the server and run

`npm install --save axios@0.18.1`

this will downgrade the version of Axios from latest to 0.18.1